# Why does Asta not use Anti-magic to nullify Megiculas curse on Lolopechka

Tags: black-clover

After finding out about Megiculas curse on Lolopechka, I am still very surprised that Asta never tried to nullify it with anti-magic. After all, curses are just spells with lingering effects, and it's been shown that the demon destroyer blade that Asta possesses is capable of absorbing and nullifying magic, even the ones with long lasting effects.

So how come he's not tried to dispel the curse, especially since it chirping off her life force drastically?

Comment: Remeber Asta could't undo the curse placed on his hands and needed the assitancee of witch queen.

Comment: It probably doesn't work like that. A curse isn't palpable magic like most of the spells that Asta nullifies in combat so for him to nullify a curse would require to know human anatomy and curse history, stuff like that to identify where the curse resides in the body and how complex it is. But anything goes, he could very well be able to nullify anything.

Comment: @RigaCrypto Anti-magic naturally opposes and negates all kinds of magic/ mana. Irrespective of their grade / level / class. During the elves arc, all he needed to dispel the reincarnation magic  which mind you, is probably one of the greatest / most complex of magical spells was simply to use the demon destroyer , without needing to know where the elves spirit was residing in the individuals. The same concept technically should be possible i guess

Comment: @Ch.SivaRamKishore True that was before he learned about how to use ki to control the flow of anti-magic in his body. But yea there could be a potential connection there

Answer (score -1):

I believe the only reason he didn't tried doing it could have been due the fact that maybe just like the curses on his hand, loropechika's curse was also residing deep underneath the flesh to stabbing someone with a rusted sword deep in their solar plexus won't have been that much of a help. Also there's a possibility that it would have shortened her lifespan from months to hours probably

Answer (score -2):

The reason Asta didnt use the Demon-Destroyer sword on the curse binded to the queen of hearts is because the author wants it that way. ans that "way" is to say Asta is also somehow quite very stupid person along with other main protagonist in other anime like Goku, Naruto, Ichigo, Luffy, Sakuragi. Be Aware that the author made all this that way. Asta's Demon Destroyer sword can nullify even demon curses as seen when he uses it against Patry in elf arc. If he uses that demon destroyer on the queen it will be a dead end of the story. I say its a good job the author prolong the story by making Asta as the Bakasta! he truly is Stupidsta and that makes the story even funnier and really good to watch. All the commedy in Black Clover is truly amazing thats all.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.